# Creating a new column with an if function in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I am currently dealing with data on NFL Teams. Basically what I am trying to do here is create a new column titled `Conference`. I am trying to create an if function that generates the conference based off the Team in the Team column. My data set is called `NFL_DATA` and the column i am interested in is `Team` so I am using `NFL_DATA$Team`. Basically I am trying to say if `NFL_DATA$TEAM == 'Philadelphia Eagles'` or `'Dallas Cowboys'` or `'New York Giants'` or `'Washington Redskins'` Then it will equal NFC East. Then in the conference column NFC East will appear for any of these teams. I am trying to do this for all 8 conferences. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

So Far this is what I have and Im sure this is off:

```
Conference <- function(NFL_DATA$Team) {
  if (NFL_DATA$Team == 'Phiadelphia Eagles' | 'Dallas Cowboys' | 'New York Giants' | 'Washington Redskins') y <- "NFC EAST"
}
```

Comment: `NFL_DATA$Conference <- NA; NFL_DATA$Conference[NFL_DATA$Team %in% c('Phiadelphia Eagles', 'Dallas Cowboys', 'New York Giants', 'Washington Redskins')] <- 'NFC_EAST'`, though a this really works better with [a lookup table](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html#applications)

Comment: If you want to do this for more conferences, have a look at `?dplyr::case_when`. But first you might learn some R-basics first...

Comment: Or you write it all using @alistaire's approach, if you want to do it for all 8 instead of using nested `ifelse` or `case_when`.

Comment: @Tino If you're using base R instead of dplyr, there's no need for nested `ifelse`s because you can assign by subset on separate lines. In dplyr, `case_when` is a better way to go because you can't assign by subset.

Comment: @Tino It's really unnecessary to call out "his obvious lack of experience in R". That's why he's asking a question; he shouldn't be shamed for it.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a function here:

```
east <- c('Phiadelphia Eagles', 'Dallas Cowboys', 'New York Giants', 'Washington Redskins')

transform(NFL_DATA, Conference = ifelse(Team %in% east, "NFC EAST", "something else")
```

Comment: How would this look like if there are more than two cases?

Comment: Feel free to use as many nested `ifelse` as you need ;-). But in general, your approach will be less messy then. I did not vote it down btw. But you might consider not using `t` as a variable, because it's a function (`?t`).

Answer (score 0):

Dplyr's case_when is handy for long ifelse statments:

```
library(dplyr)
NFL_Data <-
  NFL_Data %>% mutate("Conference" = case_when(
    Team %in% c(
      'Phiadelphia Eagles' ,
      'Dallas Cowboys' ,
      'New York Giants' ,
      'Washington Redskins'
    ) ~ 'NFC EAST',
    Team %in% c(
      'New England Patriots' ,
      'Buffalo Bills' ,
      'New York Jets' ,
      'Miami Dolphins'
    ) ~ 'AFC EAST',
    TRUE ~ "NFC WEST"
  )
```

You can keep adding `Team %in% c("List_of_Teams") ~ "Conference_Name"` lines before the `TRUE ~ "NFC WEST"` for the remaining NFL conferences.